# What's a good way to filter data based on values that match the right of the decimal place?

Tags: sql, sql-server, numbers, filtering

Let's say I have the following data in a `decimal (18,9)` identity column in a database table:

```
ID
========
1000.00
1001.23
1002.00
1003.23
```

I want to write a SQL query that returns only those records that have `.230000000` for the right side of the decimal place, such that only the following are returned:

```
1001.23
1003.23
```

I know I could do this by converting it to a string a doing a string comparison, but is there a better way that doesn't involve string comparison and is more efficient at handling numeric values?

---

Based on [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578166/whats-a-good-way-to-filter-data-based-on-values-that-match-the-right-of-the-deci/3578220#3578220), I think the best solution to use is like so:

```
Abs(ID - Cast(ID As int))
```

I added the `Abs()` function to work with negative numbers.

I ran the following tests to make sure I wasn't getting wierd rounding errors:

```
Declare @ID decimal(18,9)

Set @ID = 1000.000000000
Select @ID, Abs(@ID - Cast(@ID As int))
-- Returns: 1000.000000000  0.000000000

Set @ID = -1000.000000000
Select @ID, Abs(@ID - Cast(@ID As int))
-- Returns: -1000.000000000 0.000000000

Set @ID = 1000.000000001
Select @ID, Abs(@ID - Cast(@ID As int))
-- Returns: 1000.000000001  0.000000001

Set @ID = -1000.000000001
Select @ID, Abs(@ID - Cast(@ID As int))
-- Returns: -1000.000000001 0.000000001

Set @ID = 1000.999999999
Select @ID, Abs(@ID - Cast(@ID As int))
-- Returns: 1000.999999999  0.999999999

Set @ID = -1000.999999999
Select @ID, Abs(@ID - Cast(@ID As int))
-- Returns: -1000.999999999 0.999999999
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you create a persisted computed column

```
id - cast(id as int)
```

So you can then index it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Is there a a reason you prefer `cast` as `int` versus `Round`? I'm always scared by implicit rounding when casting.  Also, good suggestion on computed column, but I'm not going to be able to add columns to this table.

Comment: @Ben - I cast as `int` as I wasn't sure if you would be dealing with decimal values >0.5 that would then get rounded up rather than down. `select 3.7 - ROUND(3.7, 0)` gives `-0.3` for example.

Comment: Ok.  I suppose my main concern is that I need to be able to trust that `cast` as `int` always returns the integral portion of a number by simply dropping the decimal values.

Comment: Yes that is how it works. Try `select cast(0.99999 as int), cast(1.9999 as int), cast(-.99999 as int), cast(-1.9999 as int)`

Comment: that worked perfectly. I added the `Abs()` function to work with negative numbers (though I don't anticipate needing that with my ID column).  I've also updated my question with some tests that prove what you were saying. Much thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    [ID]
FROM
    [TABLE]
WHERE
    [ID] - ROUND([ID], 0) = .23
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  Is there a reason you are using `Round` versus another method?  I've gotten burned by `Round` in other languages/platforms where it didn't behave exactly as I expected.

Comment: In the past I've used casts, but that just completely slipped my mind whilst answering ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT MyCol
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyCol - ROUND(MyCol, 0) = .23
```